# Progress 4GL code analysis tool

Tags: code-analysis, progress-4gl

I know the community around Progress 4GL is highly lacking in activity, but the people on SO are a surprisingly resourceful bunch of guys!

I'm looking for a tool that is capable of creating a dependency tree for classes, include files, and other structures in Progress 4GL. Ideally it would have a command line interface so that it can be integrated into an automated build.

I would like to avoid rolling my own if I can help it. We have a 4Mloc code base, so a manually-generated dependency graph just won't work out very well. Is there any hope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very active community, but you need to know where to look. :)

- See http://www.joanju.com/ for several tools which might be useful.
- [BravePoint](http://www.bravepoint.com/) might have some resources, but probably not free.
- Also http://www.oehive.org/

Comment: SFAIK Bravepoint doesn't have anything for this kind of analysis.  The Joanju tools should be just the ticket though.  There is also a workshop being offered and a couple of breakout sessions on the topic at PUG Challenge Americas (June 5-8, Westford MA) http://pugchallenge.org

Comment: Joanju has a useful tool, but it's also over $8000. This is unfortunate when you can get free tools for other languages. This is what I meant by a lacking community. The members of the community seem mostly like consultants.

Comment: You could start with Proparse, which is free, and decide if your time is worth $8,000 or not to go the rest of the way.  It beats the heck out of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the free 10-year-old app below will do some of what you require, but was written for legacy Progress versions (ie. it will only recognize direct old-fashioned RUNs and includes, I think). As for rolling your own, or getting a start, it was written in c++ and the author may still have the source code if you email him...

[Here's the link to the app](http://freespace.virgin.net/chris.peacock/software/progressfile.htm)

The Progress community can be found at various places in addition to the above (eg. Peg.com, ProgressTalk.com, PSDN.com, etc.), is relatively minute, but is hardly inactive.

Answer (score 0):

My xref->TT tool can take apart xref strings from the COMPILE XREF statement and turns it into a set of temp-tables. You could then take that the temp-tables and use them to populate a database, after which I'm sure you'll  post your code back to the community so others can take advantage of it. :)

I stopped working on it around ~2008, so it pre-dates the OOABL structures.

See  http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-16588